# applyColorMap does not work; template matching influence

Tags: c++, opencv

It seems that there is some influence of the template matching code which won't let me apply a colour map. 
According to the documentation the type

> grayscale or colored does not matter.

Here is my code:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

/// Global Variables
Mat img;
Mat templ;
Mat result;
const char* image_window = "Source Image";
const char* result_window = "Result window";

int match_method;
int max_Trackbar = 5;

/// Function Headers
void MatchingMethod( int, void* );

int main( int, char** argv )
{
    /// Load image and template
    img = imread( argv[1], 1 );
    templ = imread( argv[2], 1 );

    /// Create windows
    namedWindow( image_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( result_window, WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

    /// Create Trackbar
    const char* trackbar_label = "Method: \n 0: SQDIFF \n 1: SQDIFF NORMED \n 2: TM CCORR \n 3: TM CCORR NORMED \n 4: TM COEFF \n 5: TM COEFF NORMED";
    createTrackbar( trackbar_label, image_window, &match_method, max_Trackbar, MatchingMethod );

    MatchingMethod( 0, 0 );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}

void MatchingMethod( int, void* )
{
    /// Source image to display
    Mat img_display;
    img.copyTo( img_display );

    /// Create the result matrix
    int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;

    result.create( result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1 );

    /// Do the Matching and Normalize
    matchTemplate( img, templ, result, match_method );
    normalize( result, result, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );

    /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
    Point matchLoc;

    minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, Mat() );


    if( match_method  == TM_SQDIFF || match_method == TM_SQDIFF_NORMED )
    { matchLoc = minLoc; }
    else
    { matchLoc = maxLoc; }


    applyColorMap(result, result, COLORMAP_JET);

    /// Show me what we got
    rectangle( img_display, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );
    rectangle( result, matchLoc, Point( matchLoc.x + templ.cols , matchLoc.y + templ.rows ), Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0 );

    cout << endl << "Type result: " << result.type() << endl;
    cout << endl << "Type img_display: " << img_display.type() << endl;
    //cout << endl << "Type result: " << result.type() << endl;

    imshow( image_window, img_display );
    imshow( result_window, result );

    return;
}
```

Regarding the documentation ([colormaps](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html?highlight=colormap#void%20applyColorMap(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20int%20colormap))) I don't see what I may have missed.
The resulting image is still grayscale.

Comment: think of it, it's just a LUT, so your input to this has to be CV_8U, not CV_32F

Answer (score 1):

I have been having the same problem.  I believe the error is found here and reported as a bug.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/6149

Not sure if its the same thing for you, but my matrix was using CV_32C1 and thus did not work.  When I changed to CV_U8C1 i got color output at least.

Answer (score 0):

Result matrix needed to be created in function. This explained in documentation clearly. So , you should try something like below.

```
Mat coloredResult;    
applyColorMap(result, coloredResult , COLORMAP_JET);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: i tried now to change the type to CV_8UC1 and applied your proposition in all combinations but unfortunately this won't solve the problem. the resulting image is still greyscale.